# objective and constraint - motion planning

Tags: algorithm, graph, graph-theory, motion-planning

What is an objective and a constraint with respect to motion planning?

Comment: [https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/D*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/D*)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is an objective and a constraint with respect to motion planning?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41200343/what-is-an-objective-and-a-constraint-with-respect-to-motion-planning)

Answer (score 0):

Taking motion planning for a robot arm for example:

- **Objective**: the desired pose for your end effector. An objective, as seen in the implementation of OMPL, could also be in the form of a goal constraint. Instead of having a single pose as the goal, the objective could be a hypersphere in the configuration space.
- **Constraint**: this may come in many forms. On top of my head: keeping the arm collision free along the trajectory; maximum torque constraints; if an object has been picked, keeping it level all the time along the trajectory; etc.